# How to return value from the method in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

It might be a small question, but i am not understanding why it is throwing error.

### Error:

> Use of unassigned local variable status.

```
        public static bool HandleError(int eventId, int transactionId, DateTime timestamp, int userId, string message)
        {
            static bool status;
            ErrorMessage objHandleError = new ErrorMessage();
            try
            {
                objHandleError.EventId = eventId;
                objHandleError.TransactionId = transactionId;
                objHandleError.Timestamp = timestamp;
                objHandleError.UserId = userId;
                objHandleError.Message = message;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objHandleError.Message))
                {
                    status = false;
                }
                else
                    status = true;
                // Places the recived object on the service bus
                MessageBroadcastHelper.Send("ErrorMessage", objHandleError);

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //To Do : if any exception we may write this exception to the event log.
                objHandleError.Exception = ex.ToString();
                //string ExceptionString = SerializeException(ex);            
            }

 return status;
        }
```

if i declare status variable in the class level,it is not throwing any exception, if i declare status variable outside the class i am not getting any errors.

Since i am using this variable only inside this method, i don't want to expose it out side, can any body point me what was the problem in the below code.

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: I guess the problem is with your try catch block, whenever any exception occur before assigning value to status variable then at that time your method will return null

Comment: @Damien:Edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1) You've declared a local variable a static. That's invalid.

2) If an exception is thrown early in your method, you're catching it and then trying to return `status` without ever assigning a value to it.

I would suggest that in most cases you don't want to catch the exception at all - or if you *do* want to catch it (e.g. for logging), you should usually then use `throw;` to let it propagate up. If you really, really want to catch the exception and not rethrow it, you need to work out what value you want to be returned.

(I'd *also* suggest not catching bare `Exception` even if you do want to catch *some* exceptions. You should almost always catch a *specific* exception.)

To be honest, it's not clear how much use the returned value is anyway - the caller is passing in the message, so it's easy enough for *them* to check whether it's null or empty...

Comment: As you said removed static, and if i place my return statement in the try block, method is returning "not all code paths return value"

Comment: :If an exception is thrown early in your method, you're catching it and then trying to return status without ever assigning a value to it.:  if message not equals null i am assigning value true and if it is null assigning false then only i am returning in try block

Comment: @Chiranjeevi: Well yes, you still haven't described what you want to be returned if you catch an exception...

Comment: in catch i am trying to write exception to the event log.means i do not want to return any thing.

Comment: @Chiranjeevi: Well what *do* you want to happen? Should the computer just shut down at that point? Go into an infinite loop? I suspect not - so you *either* need to return from the method (with a value) *or* rethrow the exception.

Comment: Thank you for making me understand, i set status=false in catch block.